# xfce pulseaudio plugin -- volume control doesn't change to bluetooth output on connecting

Tags: xfce, pulseaudio, bluetooth

i use the xfce-pulseaudio-plugin in my panel (running xfce on debian buster). i would like for the keyboard volume controls to switch to controlling a bluetooth speaker when it is connected, but this doesn't happen.

on successfully establishing a bluetooth connection, the controls do nothing, and if i click the plugin, the output device displayed hasn't updated. to get my controls to work i have to open the plugin, hover over "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" and then select my bluetooth device from the dropdown bullet menu that appears.

its only the controls that don't change. the audio output changes fine, and if i open 'audio mixer' (pavucontrol) from within the plugin it has correctly switched to the bluetooth device.

adjusting volume works there, or from the command line with `pactl set-sink-volume` too.

basically i wd like my hardware controls to switch to working on whatever is currently outputting sound.

edit:
i also have alsamixer installed, which i don't know anything about and don't know if is relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case it was that `module-switch-on-connect` was not loaded, adding `load-module module-switch-on-connect` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` should fix the issue unless. you can check currently loaded modules with `pactl list modules`. if adding it to the conf file doesn't work, you can add `pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect` to your `~/.xsessionrc`.

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=58124#p58124
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=13040